# How do I make my overloaded operators behave correctly with built-in types in Python?

Tags: python, oop

It feels like such a simple thing but I can't seem to find the info I need.
Say I define a class Matrix:

```
class Matrix():
    def __mul__(self, other):
    if isinstance(other, Matrix):
        #Matrix multiplication.
    if isinstance(other, int): #or float, or whatever
        #Matrix multiplied cell by cell.
```

This work fine if I multiply a matrix by an int, but since int doesn't know how to deal with matrices, 3*Matrix raises a TypeError.
How do I deal with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define `__rmul__` to override the calling of `int()`'s `__mul__` method:

```
class Matrix():
    # code

    def __rmul__(self, other):
        #define right multiplication here.

        #As Ignacio said, this is the ideal
        #place to define matrix-matrix multiplication as __rmul__() will
        #override __mul__().

    # code
```

Note that you [can do this with all of the numeric operators](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types).

Also note that it's better to use new style classes, so define your class as:

```
class Matrix(object):
```

This will allow you to do things like:

```
if type(other) == Matrix: ...
```

Comment: Note that matrix multiplication is *not* commutative, so this implementation will DTWT when someone comes along and defines a new matrix type that is meant to be compatible with this one.

Comment: `isinstance(other, Matrix)` is better than direct `type` checking because it supports subclassing.

Comment: @agf: where does `issubclass()` fall into this?

Comment: @JoelCornett `issubclass` tests if a __class__ is a subclass of another class, not whether an object is an __instance__ of a class or its subclasses, which is what `isinstance` does.

Answer (score 1):

Define the [`__rmul__()`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__radd__) method as well.

Comment: Gah! Still not sure how I'd have found it looking by myself. Thanks.